# ifstream: Skip reading lines containing NaN

Tags: c++, ifstream, nan

I'm reading a text file using ifstream on VS2012 C++. Is there a simple way to skip reading lines that contain "NaN"?

```
ifstream loadFile;
loadFile.open("data.txt", ios::in);

double x;
int numLine = 3;
int numCol = 4;
vector< vector<int> > data(numLine, vector<int> numCol);

for( int i=0; i< numLine; i++){
    for ( int j=0; j< numCol; j++){
        loadFile >> x ;
        data[i][j] = x;
    }
}
```

File sample:

```
2.4 4.6 6.8 0.34
5.34 3.4 NaN 1.1 
2 -4 -6 5
```

Comment: Your lines are records? I mean, does each line contain 4 numbers?

Comment: yes, each line contains 4 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to detect that the input string was literally `"NaN"` but you can do

```
if (!(loadFile>>x)) // Read might fail on "NaN"
{
    loadFile.clear(); // Reset error state
    loadFile.ignore(3); // This assumes we only fail on NaN.
}
```

This ignores just the single input. Of course, if your input can contain `-NaN` or other inputs with length!=3 then you need to be a bit smarter. And if you need to ignore the whole line, then you need to reset `i` after the bad line.

Comment: Yes, I need to ignore the whole line. clear() makes it work! Also good to know about ignore(). Thanks.

Comment: @askingtoomuch This skips only one number, not the whole line. How can *it work*? Isn't it much better to work on whole input lines?

Comment: @Wolf: You make it work by continuing with the entire line as if nothing happened, only setting a flag "badLine". At the end of the line, if the flag is set, decrease `i` (line index) and clear the flag. This overwrites the `data[i][*]` entries.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for the reply, I really wished to make look the asker on this. To me, it still seems preferable to divide the task into reading entire records (say lines) and reading 4 numbers from a line.

Comment: @Wolf I actually thought of that also. Do you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: @askingtoomuch you may want to have a look on [this little sketch](https://ideone.com/RwzCgv). I'm not happy with nesting record processing into line processing and have absolutely no clue about the performance of this usage of `std::stringstream` for each line...

Comment: @Wolf thanks for sharing your solution. It looks simple. I could just add a few more lines and achieve my task.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `isnan` function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan

Comment: I couldn't read "NaN" as I'm reading "double". One of the solution to my problem is to read "string". I just wonder if there's any simple solution if I just want to read "double".

Comment: In my code above, the value of x doesn't read in any value when it reads a "NaN", it keeps the previous value and stuck there til the end of the loops. Something like this: 5.34 3.4 3.4 3.4 
3.4 3.4 3.4

Comment: Doesn't work. The read fails, and `x` is never set to NaN as a result.